ROS2 (Jazzy) Gz ignition (Harmonic) Question about description pkg
I'm new on gz ignition and ros jazzy (actually new on ros2).
I'm trying to make a simulation, and noticed that gazebo ignition has the completely different API. Sadly, I found that this new tech is less likely to be talked in forums, but then, I found out that gz has already made an template repository for someone to start the projects. I have two question about this

It has file named after extensions ".dsv.in" and ".sh.in". What are those actually?
They provided template for sdf, but can I use like urdf xacro for it? I noticed that in  the worlds file they included the model. If I can use urdf xacro, how can I do that?

<include merge="true">
        <uri>package://namr_simulator/models/namr</uri>
</include>

Thank you, your help may made a pretty huge impact for my future development for this

I am quite new to Gazebo Harmonic too, I have not looked into question 1. yet but as for 2.:
You are not able to include .urdf.xacro directly in sdf. Gazebo does have a a conversion command:
$ xacro my_xacro.urdf.xacro > my_urdf.urdf
$ gz sdf -p my_urdf.urdf > model.sdf

To properly include this in your world.sdf use the directory architecture as seen in the ros_gz_sim README.md:

my_awesome_pkg
├── models
│   └── cool_robot
│       ├── model.config
│       └── model.sdf
└── package.xml


And calling it in the world.sdf:

<sdf version="1.6">
 <world name="default">
   <include>
     <uri>package://my_awesome_pkg/models/cool_robot</uri>
   </include>
 </world>
</sdf>


Another method to spawn a model into a Gazebo simulation from ROS2 is running the ros_gz_sim create node (ros_gz_sim create.cpp).

ros2 run ros_gz_sim create -world default -file 'path/to/model'

Alternatively in a .launch.py publishing the urdf to the topic /robot_description and spawning it into Gazebo with:
ros_gz_spawner_cmd = Node(
    package='ros_gz_sim',
    executable='create',
    arguments=[
        '-topic', "robot_description",
        '-name', "robot_name",
        '-allow_renaming', 'true',
        '-x', "0.0",
        '-y', "0.0",
        '-z', "0.0",
        '-R', "0.0",
        '-P', "0.0",
        '-Y', "0.0"
    ],
    output='screen'
)



It has file named after extensions ".dsv.in" and ".sh.in". What are those actually?

Those are files used by colcon to set environment variables. See https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/released/developer/environment.html#dsv-files. For Gazebo, it's used to set the GZ_SIM_RESOURCE_PATH environment variable which tells Gazebo where to search for resources such a as SDF or URDF models, mesh files, etc.

They provided template for sdf, but can I use like urdf xacro for it? I noticed that in the worlds file they included the model. If I can use urdf xacro, how can I do that?

xacro files cannot be used inside SDF directly, instead you'll have to convert it to a URDF first. You have two options to do this:

Convert the file and save as a URDF in your project and include that in the SDF file via an <include> tag.
Convert the xacro file on the fly in a ROS launch file and use the create node from ros_gz_sim which accepts a the converted URDF string. Here's an example. This is similar to the answer by @JustPtrck, but you shouldn't have to convert to SDF. Gazebo supports URDF files natively.


Thank you so much fellas, you saved my life
